Frobenius Theorem on real division algebras - proof with quaternions
I find Frobenius' Theorem on real division algebras most particularly interesting and beautiful.
I have read about some proofs, but I am looking for a proof using specifically quaternions. Does anybody have knowledge of one?
I am searching for a proof which uses quaternions in a "relevant" way.

https://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/seminar/Barr-notes_on_real_div_alg.pdf

https://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1445553/FULLTEXT01.pdf

What are you hoping for?  The only thing I can imagine is proving the only $\mathbb R$-algebra which is an $\mathbb H$-algebra is $\mathbb H$, and showing the only ones which aren't $\mathbb H$-algebras are $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$.  Though I don't see why this wouldn't be a manufactured proof.
